# How to configure WebStorm to work with nx lint instead of ESLint?

Tags: eslint, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, nx.dev

When working on nx projects with WebStorm (and probably with other JetBrains IDEs) I keep getting this error:

> Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.

I do have the `parserOptions.project` defined in the `libs/mylibrary/.eslintrs.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.*?.json",
    "tsconfigRootDir": "./libs/mylibrary"
  },
  ...
```

The error does not reproduce when I run ESLint manually, via `npx eslint ./libs/mylibrary` or via nx (`nx lint mylibrary`).

Any idea how to configure WebStorm to work well with `nx lint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be a problem with wrong working folder the linter is run in. With **Automatic** configuration, the ESlint working folder is set to a folder where the nearest `.eslintrc` or `eslintignore` resides (as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_manual_configuration)
If the auto-detected working directory doesn't match your project configuration, you need to specify the working directory (directories) manually: in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint**, change configuration to **Manual** and specify the directory in which you run `eslint --fix` in terminal (project root folder?) as a working dir - this should solve the issue

Comment: great! thanks, seems to be working properly now

Comment: Adding a comment since I wasn't sure what the working directory is supposed to be. I put the path to my root `eslintsrc.js` and it started working, otherwise, it was trying to work with the `eslintsrc.json` in each of the projects in my monorepo and it kept having a problem finding the tsconfig files configured in those subfolders.

Comment: Thank you, you're the one! My experience with Nx and Webstorm was pretty awful, now I can finally run `eslint --fix` on save, wonderful.